# Handlebars triple-stash to avoid escaping html entities

Tags: encoding, handlebars.js

I use handlebars, and if an escaped character such as `&#39;` is processed it is rendered on screen as `&#39;`.

I know wrapping the variable in a triple-stash will prevent this.

I processed the following string within a triple-stash as a quick test and it seemed fine "`<p>hello<p>`wouldn't wouldn`&#39;`t" This rendered to screen exactly how I wanted it to.

My question is, is it safe to simply wrap all variables in triple-stash? or will this have some unforeseen consequences I haven't considered?

Thanks

Comment: It's safe only when you have pre-escaped variables. Otherwise variables containing some kind of user-defined data may cause XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Thanks  very much - A lot of this work is about Xss attacks so im hapy to accept if you want to make that an asnwer

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default all double-stashed `{{var}}` embeds in Handlebars will be HTML-escaped. It's performed for security reasons to avoid [DOM XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) vulnerabilities. Because your variable may contain any data including user-data or any kind of untrusted data.

In some cases you will need to embed your data as-is, without escaping. There is where tripple-stash `{{{var}}}` used. But every time doing this, you need to think *what* may be in your data and can you trust it?

Read more about [HTML Escaping](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping) on Handlebars site.