# What is the difference between double curly braces and triple curly braces for Handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

For instance, you can see `{{{body}}}` and in the templates, you are able to do something like `{{data.page.hero.text}}`

Is there any significant difference we should be aware of?

Comment: This will help you out : `https://stackoverflow.com/a/27939810/8536103`

Comment: For more information : `http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html`

Comment: thanks, do we have to use {{{}}} for helpers as well? Like `{{{link story}}}` ??

Answer (score 28):

Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

Reference: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#html-escaping

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use case and logic, you may add an option "noEscape" set to true when compiling the template if you want to use {{ }} when {{{ }}} are required to successfully replace the templates.
For example: replacing with JSON values.

From the documentation:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('{{foo}}', { noEscape: true });
```

**noEscape**: Set to true to not HTML escape any content.